# If $p, q, r$ and $s$ are in continued proportion. Then find the minimum value of $\frac{p-s}{q-r}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My approach: We have, $\frac pq=\frac qr=\frac rs.$ Which implies $q^2=pr$ and $r^2=qs.$ On dividing we get:

$\frac{q^2}{r^2}=\frac{pr}{qs}$

$\implies \frac{q^3}{r^3}=\frac{p}{s}$

$\implies \frac{q^3-r^3}{r^3}=\frac{p-s}{s}$

\begin{align}
\implies\frac{p-s}{q-r}&=\frac{s(q^2+qr+r^2)}{r^3}\\\\
&=\frac{s(q^2+qr+r^2)}{qs\cdot r},\text{ as }r^2=qs\\\\
&=\frac{q^2+qr+r^2}{qr}\quad ... (1) 
\end{align}

Now $(q-r) ^2\ge 0,$ true for all real $q$ and $r$. This gives

$q^2+r^2\ge 2qr\implies q^2+qr+r^2\ge 3qr.$

If $qr>0, $ then from $(1),$

$\min\left(\frac{p-s}{q-r}\right)=3.$

But I'm confused how to approach the same if $qr<0.$ Please suggest... (No additional informations were given in the question and I don't know the answer. I found this question on Quora, no one has answered it.)

Comment: If the ratio is negative there is no minimum.  In general, if the ratio is $\tau$ then your expression is $\frac {\tau^2+\tau+1}{\tau}$ which goes to $-\infty$ for $\tau\to -\infty$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$\frac pq = \frac qr = \frac rs := a$$

We can express ratios in terms of $a$:

$$\frac pq = a \qquad \qquad \frac rq = \frac 1a \qquad \qquad \frac sq = \frac sr \frac rq = \frac{1}{a^2}$$

Hence, the expression becomes

$$\frac{p-s}{q-r} = \frac{\frac pq - \frac sq}{1 - \frac rq} = \frac{a - \frac{1}{a^2}}{1-\frac 1a} = \frac{a^3-1}{a^2-a} = \frac{a^2+a+1}{a}$$

assuming that $q \neq 0$, $a \neq 0$, and $a-1\neq 0$. Differentiating,

$$\frac{d}{da}\frac{a^2+a+1}{a}=0 \iff 1-\frac{1}{a^2} =0  \iff a = \pm 1$$

We compute

$$\frac{a^2+a+1}{a} \bigg|_{a=1} = 3 \qquad \qquad \frac{a^2+a+1}{a} \bigg|_{a=-1} = -1$$

Assuming that the ratio must be positive the minimum value is indeed $3$.

If the ratio is allowed to be negative, then clearly

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{a^2+a+1}{a} = -\infty$$

so there is no minimum.

Comment: Yeah, i just realised. Fixing it right now

Comment: Never said that. In the second line of my answer, I stated that $\frac rq = \frac 1a$

Comment: And, as both @lulu and I pointed out, if the ratio is allowed to be negative, then there is no minimum. Thus, $qr$ must be positive; which is why you were unable to find a solution in the case $qr<0$.

Comment: Sorry for that comment. I didn't notice properly. Thank you so much for your precious time.

Comment: We have $$\frac{a^2+a+1}{a} =\frac1a+a+1.$$ Now use the (well known) result that $a+1/a$ is minimal if $a=1$ for positive $a$.